# Deploying to Weblogic 10.3.6 from Eclipse -- "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server."

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, weblogic

I have a Spring Boot application. I build it with Maven. I have the pom configured to produce a Weblogic-compatible .war file. I can deploy this war file manually via either the WebLogic console or via the weblogic-maven-plugin Maven command.

I have now added my WebLogic server and domain to my Eclipse servers panel. I can start and stop it just fine, but when I click "Add and Remove", I get:

```
There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server.
```

In my Project Facets, I have:

```
Dynamic Web Module 2.5
Java 1.7 (matches what WebLogic wants and what my pom specifies)
```

What else can I check or change?

Comment: I tried doing a "run as -> run on server", and get this error: `project facet cloud foundry standalone application version 1.0 is not supported`. I do not have that facet checked in my project properties, nor do I have any imports/dependencies in any way related to Cloud Foundry (unless they're transient dependencies through one of the Spring Boot starter dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even though I didn't have the Cloud Foundry facet checked, that was still the issue. I deleted the Cloud Foundry-related plugins from Eclipse, and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the problem might also because you did not select the dynamic web module .
To do so open your project properties then goto your Project Facets then Check/Select the Dynamic Web Module checkbox then apply & close.